# Android app sending SMS with wrong characters

Tags: android, sms

I need to send a SMS that contains a JSON in my Android app. Here is the code:

```
SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
String message = "{\"phone\":\"9999-9999\"}";
sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);
```

I tested with some phones and most part of them receive the right message:

```
{"phone":"9999-9999"}
```

But one model (LG G2 Mini) changes the '{' character when the SMS is received:

```
ä"phone":"9999-9999"ñ
```

Does anybody know why it's happening?

Any tip will be very helpful,

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are special charsets for SMS, see this link from Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GSM_03.38

The characters *{* and *}*, that are wrong on your phone, are in the *Basic Character Set Extension*. Try other are characters like *€*, *|*, *]* and so on. When these characters also do not work on your phone, I suppose your problem is related to this charset extension.

Characters from the extension need to be escaped with 0x1B (escape character in SMS). This is only a conjecture, maybe there could be a problem with the escaping.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the LG G2 Min has not correctly implemented the 3GPP TS 23.038.

SMS uses different character sets. The mostly used is the GSM 7 bit default alphabet. It codes in 7 bits most of the usual characters and special characters used by US and some European languages. Some special characters (^{}\<[~]€) did not fit into this 7 bit table. The escape character switch to GSM 7 Bit default alphabet extension table that contains the above mentioned special character. These characters are codes by two 7-Bit character, ESC and the code for e.g. ‘{‘.

What you can try, if possible, is to use Unicode. You may force Unicode by using a Unicode character in your message that is not part of the 7-Bit GSM character code and its extension table.